# Hive not support is not null in where clause for float data type

Tags: hadoop, hiveql

I was trying to filter using column is not null in where clause in a Hive Select statement.  It is not accepting it.  I tried length(cast(column as string)) >0 , it still fails, but if I try to select length(cast(column as string)) , it works fine. The Hadoop distribution, I am working on is Horton works.

Comment: Which version of Hive?? What table type?? *ORC had some issues with Nulls in older versions, for instance*

Comment: can you provide the full select statement? I guess that you try to impose a condition in the `SELECT` part and not after `WHERE`